# Laravel - Performance takes time in search form for large data

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a search form for large data (30K rows) and it takes time to show the data.

I indexed all the columns in my DB (20 columns).

This is my query:

```
SELECT corporates.name as CP_NAME,
    B.client_no, B.client_name, B.phone,
    B.draft_no, B.due_date, B.status, B.currency, B.amount, B.remarks as RK, B.created_at
    FROM ( select client_name, phone, draft_no, status, max(created_at) as created_at
    from policies group by client_name, phone, draft_no ) A
    INNER JOIN policies B USING (client_name, phone, draft_no,created_at)
    INNER JOIN corporates ON B.cust_id =corporates.id
```

How can I improve it ?

Thank you.

Comment: what db engine are you using?

Comment: Am using InnoDB

Comment: could you post an explain of your query?

Comment: In my query, am selecting `corporates.name as CP_NAME,
    B.client_no, B.client_name, B.phone,
    B.draft_no, B.due_date, B.status, B.currency, B.amount, B.remarks as RK, B.created_at` where tthe `created_at` is newest, because i have the same rows (selecting rows) but only the row `status` is changing, so i need to show the last `status` changes by the `created_at`

Comment: I meant the explain of the query!
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: https://209.97.178.237/Capture.PNG